# What is a good package for displaying algorithms?

Tags: packages, algorithms, pseudocode

I found this page with some examples:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode

I'm wondering which one to use. Any suggestions? I'm using other packages too so whichever is less likely to interfere with them is better for me.

Comment: I would suggest you change the title to something less subjective, such as "What is a good package for displaying algorithms?" or more in line with the current one "What is a good package for displaying dem algorithms?" :)

Comment: Related: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764)

Answer (score 101):

Personally, I favour `algpseudocode` from the [**`algorithmicx`**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) (note the trailing **`x`**!) package. With a bit of setup, this can be harnessed to create beautiful pseudocode.

[image: algpseudocode example]

This was produced by the following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Counting mismatches between two packed \DNA{} strings
    \label{alg:packed-dna-hamming}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed \DNA{} strings of equal length $n$}
    \Statex
    \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
      \Let{$z$}{$x \oplus y$} \Comment{$\oplus$: bitwise exclusive-or}
      \Let{$\delta$}{$0$}
      \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
        \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
          \Let{$\delta$}{$\delta + 1$}
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\delta$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

And used the following setup (this is just an example to replicate the above; you can of course use your own setup):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\newcommand*\DNA{\textsc{dna}}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{
    {\sf\footnotesize\addfontfeatures{Colour=888888,Numbers=Monospaced}#1}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondition:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondition:}}
```

To get the **`end`**-less pseudocodes, I included the package as follows:

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

---

The above pseudo code is nested inside an `algorithm` float environment. This environment isn’t part of `algorithmicx`. Instead, you need to load the package `algorithm` to get it. To produce a list of all algorithms, you can use

```
\listofalgorithms
```

For further information, see the section “The `algorithm` Environment” in the documentation of the [`algorithms`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/) package. But I want to stress again that (except for the float environment) the `algorithmicx` package is superior to `algorithms`.

Comment: can you make a `\listofalgorithms` with it? i was checking out algorithmic but it doesn't seem to have a `\function` tag which is pretty disappointing

Comment: @bada: This is **not** the `algorithmic` package, it’s `algorithmicx`, note the trailing `x`. It does have a `\Function` macro. For a list of algorithms, see updated answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am trying to run your code, but I get:
Undefined control sequence for 3rd line of algorithm block.

I would be really happy if you help me figure it out.

Comment: @Naji Just remove the `\DNA` macros or define it appropriately.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, when I ignore the error I get your box of pseudo code but there is a "Colour=888888,Numbers=Monospaced1" "Colour=888888,Numbers=Monospaced2"... in front of each line

Comment: @Naji Erm, that wasn’t what I said. But apparently your problem stems from something else: you need to load the `fontspec` package, load a font, and use XeLaTeX for compilation. Sorry, my answer should have mentioned that. See the update.

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph would you be willing to recompose your example to be a TeX compatible minimal working example, with a list of the necessary packages that need to be separately downloaded and installed in your TeX repository. Right now it requires a lot of tweaking and extant know how to be able to get your example to work. Additionally, discussing the OP's question about compatibility with other packages would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: The \Let command doesn't work for me -- any reason why?

Answer (score 18):

This is a modification of @KonradRudolph's answer, but with a minimal working example along with a list of the necessarily installed packages that did not come with the basic LaTeX build. In addition I include a brief discussion of the TeX distribution's path, how to find it, and how to add a package to it in case you don't already know how. Hopefully this is a good extraction from the original that allows people who are newer to writing with TeX the ability to use this package more directly, jumping over some of the hurdles that were left unscaled in the original answer.

First, you will need to install [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) in the path that your TeX distribution can read.

A good way to learn whether about the TeX distribution's paths covers a set of files is to walk through [this tutorial](http://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2012/11/10/installing-minion-pro/) by @kieran Healy, which describes the steps needed to make a font available to TeX, which is a much more arduous process (since you need to deal with font metric files, and have the license to the font in question, among other things).

Most importantly for the purposes here is the command

```
kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL'
```

Which should print the local directory in your distribution's path to the console. If it doesn't work, try

```
DEST=`kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL'`&& echo $DEST
```

And if that doesn't work, I'd suggest reinstalling TeXLive if you are on OS X and I have no clue what to do if you aren't.

Then, once you've identified your distribution's path and have downloaded the relevant CTAN files, create a new document and paste the following into it.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\newcommand*\DNA{\textsc{dna}}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondition:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondition:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Counting mismatches between two packed \DNA{} strings
    \label{alg:packed-dna-hamming}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed \DNA{} strings of equal length $n$}
    \Statex
    \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
      \Let{$z$}{$x \oplus y$} \Comment{$\oplus$: bitwise exclusive-or}
      \Let{$\delta$}{$0$}
      \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
        \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
          \Let{$\delta$}{$\delta + 1$}
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\delta$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Once you run the command it should produce a PDF that looks like the following image:

[image]

Note that it is slightly different than the original that Konrad posted, as the nice sans-serif numbers and fontspec are unnecessary parts for someone just interested in getting algorithms to render properly.

NB: You should embed the `algorithmic` environment inside the `algorithm` environment, so that it is treated as a single floating entity and will not be broken across multiple pages.

Comment: Got rid of the comments, good call. I'll leave the DNA bits, as using smallcaps for acronyms is generally a good practice to encourage even if just in examples. But the point is well taken. Grazie, @Austin.

Answer (score 10):

The FAQ page at https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-algorithms provides an overview of the various packages for typesetting pseudocode in LaTeX.

Comment: Dead link, and embedded search engine couldn't find the (possible) new page.

Answer (score 6):

If you like the typesetting used in the **Introduction to Algorithm**, here is the page for [clrscode](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/), which includes package for both the second and third edition.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using listings package with `mathescape=true` option and a language definition to make it highlight my keywords. Something like that:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{alg}{
morekeywords={def,if,then,else,while,do,assert,end}
}
```