# Best solution to present school computing algorithm

Tags: xetex, algorithms

I need to typeset some computing class algorithms like:

```
Repeat
 Accept Roll_Number
If (the Roll Number has already been added to the absent list) then 
 Prompt”You have already added the roll number to the absent list”
Else
         Continue with the adding process
End if
         Connect to the Student’s table of Malpi’s database
Search for the match of Roll_Number
If (the match is found) Then
         Display Student’s firstname,middlename,lastname,guardianname,contactnumber
Else
         Don’t Display Anything
End If
Until (all the absent students have been added to the absent list)
Open the absent file where the records are to be added
Repeat
         If (the student has already been added to the file for that day) Then
                  Prompt” The student has already been added to the file”
         Else
                  Continue
         End if
Until (All the Roll_Number in the list have been checked)
Get the record number of the last record in the absent file
Open the absent file where the records are to be added
Repeat
        Add 1 to the record number
        Save the student’s absent details to the file
Until (the records of all the students are saved in the absent file)
```

What is the best way to represent this in XeTeX ? I tried using \verbatim package but it seems to break margins ? Is there any good to present this ?

Comment: I realise these are dumb questions, however their answers are bound to help us understand your problem. A) what's holding you back from rearranging your text into shorter lines? B) what's the problem with typesetting your text in a smaller font size? C) Why can't you typeset your text in `tt` and issue successions of `\quad`'s or `\qquad`'s for indentation without dropping into `\verb` et al?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to rearrange them into shorter lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use “normal” text instead of `\verbatim`? A list (`enumerate`) would be well suited, I think. I don’t think `\verbatim` really offers any advantage here and I wouldn’t necessarily choose a typesetting font here, either: it’s an *algorithm*, not *source code*.

Alternatively, you could try one of the [pseudo-code typesetting packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-a-good-package-for-displaying-algorithms).

Personally, I prefer [flowchart diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) to display algorithms but I don’t know a good way of typesetting them in LaTeX (besides using TikZ or PSTtricks, of course).

Comment: I am also adding flowcharts with this. After checking out TikZ and PSTtricks. I am simply draw and use high-res images. There is no ant LaTeXy way for flowchart.