# Create a keyword using the newalg package and algkey

Tags: algorithms

I'm using the [newalg](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=newalg) package to typeset some algorithms, and I'd like to be able to typeset a keyword using the algkey macro. the problem is that I can't get it to work. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
\begin{algorithm}{PromoteServer}{x}
servers \= \CALL{GetMeshServers}(x) \\
\begin{FOR}{\EACH M_n \IN servers}
    \begin{IF}{n \eq \algkey{sizeof}(servers)}
    \ELSE
    \end{IF}
    \CALL{AssignCachePartner}(M_{n+1})
\end{FOR}
\end{algorithm}
```

Where am I going wrong? The documentation for the package doesn't give any examples....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of the package is from 2005, it doesn’t ship with TeX Live, the documentation is very incomplete and promises “future work” … I don’t think this package is supported any longer. **Try using** [**another package**, e.g. `algpseudocode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-a-good-package-for-displaying-algorithms/1376#1376), or Cormen’s own [`clrscode`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/clrscode).

That said, *what do you mean by* “I can't get it to work”? The code, as you’ve written it, is correct. I’ve had a look at the source code of the package and `\algkey` is defined as follows:

```
\def\algkey#1{\mbox{\bf #1\ }}
```

So there’s absolutely nothing special about that command (apart from the fact that it always appends a space which may be unwanted) and it should work out of the box. Alternatively, you can just use `\textbf{sizeof}` to get the same effect, minus the annoying space at the end.