# Recursive algorithms with the »algorithms« package?

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I need to write a recursive algorithm, using the [algorithms](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) package.

I thought of writing something like this:

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\IF {$x=1}
    \RETURN 1
\ELSE
    \RETURN recurse$(x-1)$
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
```

The problem here is that it's not obvious that the function "recurse" will call this very function (that is unnamed to start with) again. Is there a better way of doing it, besides stating in the text that "recurse" - well, recurses?

Comment: In your original question it said "`algorithmic` package". Did you mean `algorithmicx` or `algorithms` (or maybe even `algorithm2e`)?

Comment: Sorry for my detailed response - the packages I import are
\usepackage{algorithm} and
\usepackage{algorithmic}
. When I first wrote the algorithms, I did not know which package to used, and a Google search suggested that these were the packages usually used - hence I formatted my algorithms with these in mind. I can re-write them for a new package, of course, if it offers a solution to my problem.

Comment: That should read "delayed" instead of "detailed". I will use the algorithmicx package as Konrad suggested - being able to encapsulate the algorithm in a procedure should be the least ambiguous way of describing recursion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a way of defining procedures in `algorithms` but you *can* use an `algorithm` environment with an appropriate `\caption` that names your algorithm.

Personally, though, I would switch to the [superior `algorithmicx` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1375/42#1376) that defines a `\Procedure` macro:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\Procedure{recurse}{$x$}
  \If{$x=1$}
    \State\Return{$1$}
  \Else
    \State\Return{\Call{recurse}{$x-1$}}
  \EndIf
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: It _may_ be that the OP is already using `algorithmicx`; see my comment to the question. (Doesn't matter too much for your answer `:-)`)

Comment: A procedure macro was exactly what I was hoping for. The syntax of the algorithmicx package seems quite similar to the algorithmic package, so there should be little overhead rewriting the algorithms. Thank you, Konrad.