# Print programs with its proper syntax

Tags: spacing, minipage, code

I have defined my own language whose syntax is very close to the one of Pascal. I would like to type the following program for instance. Many people use the packages `algorithmicx` or `algorithm2e` to print programs, but it seems that we have to use their specific keywords of its syntax like `procedure`, `end while`.

I just want to indent spaces when needed, and bold some words when I want (sorry that I could not **bold** letters in the following figure). Do I have to use 
`texttt` for each line? Also, with `verbatim`, I could not **bold** words...

Also, as the program is not large, I would need to put it on the left side of the page, and leave space for some explanasion text on its right hand side. So I  guss I need to get them all together, and use `multicols`.

Could anyone help?

```
program test                                      some text here
var
  i : integer;                                    ... 
  b : boolean;
begin
   i := 1;                                        ...
   b := true;
   while i < 15 do
      i := i  + 1;
      b := not b                                  some text here
   od
end
```

**Edit1:** Following @Werner's `tabbing` solution, I have made the code a minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
Werner's solution
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
a paragraph
\end{minipage}
```

Actually as the code shows, I want the texts to be another separated minipage on the right hand side of the code. I have then 2 questions:

1. is it reasonable to make `0.48\linewidth` instead of `0.5\linewidth`? `0.48\linewidth` is a conventional choice?
2. is it possible to make a frame around the code, and use `\caption` and `\label` to make it a reference (I prefer figures)?

Comment: 1) The choice of `0.48\linewidth` is to allow for some padding between the two minipages. `\hfill` completes the padding so as to use the entire `\linewidth`. 2) See my solution for framing the code - just put an `\fbox{...}` around it. You **can** put the entire thing in a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` and use `\caption` and `\label` just like you normally would for a "regular" figure.

Comment: I am sure you have seen this, but I'll add a pointer to a very similar questions, for other people to see: [Looking for style files for writing a programming language book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43761/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)

You can define your own keywords when using the `algorithmicx` package. Section **3.1.10 Changing command names** of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) discusses the use of `\algnewcommand`/`\algrenewcommand` that you can use to create a new command/change existing formatting. The following two images are taken directly from the package documentation:

[image: Algorithmicx \algnewcommand]

[image: Algorithmicx \algrenewcommand]

---

## [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)

You can also define your own keywords using the `algorithm2e` package. Section **10 To define your own language keywords** of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf) discusses this in detail. Specifically, you use commands like

- `\SetKwInput` and `\SetKwOutput` for algorithm *input* / *output* definition
- `\SetKw` for *keyword* definitions
- `\SetKwBlock` for *block* definitions
- `\SetKwFunction` for *function* / *procedure* definitions
- `\SetKwComment` for *comment* definitions
- `\SetKwIf` for *if-statement* definitions
- `\SetKwSwitch` for *multiple condition selection* definitions
- `\SetKwFor` for *for loop* definitions
- `\SetKwRepeat` for *repeat* / *while* definitions

---

## [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)

Then there's the `listings` package that allows just as much modification. Keyword definitions are specified via styles and/or languages. Read the highly detailed [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information on this.

---

## `tabbing`

The above use some rich programming directives from package that probably require a lot of reading. In the special case where you "just want to write a couple of lines of code and format stuff your own way", you could use the `tabbing` environment. This is either [provided by LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zwbk.png) (as default) or by the [`tabbing` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabbing). The [`tabbing` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/Tabbing/Tabbing.pdf) gives some motivation for using it, but that's up to you.

A typical `tabbing` environment would resemble

```
\begin{tabbing}
  <space> \= <space> \= <space> \= <space> \= \kill
  no indent \> \> more text \\
  \> one indent \> \\
  ....
  ....
\end{tabbing}
```

where the tab stops a indicated by `\=` and jumped to by using `\>`. It is best to put empty spacing in the first row (via `\hspace{<space>}`, `\quad`, `\qquad` or `\phantom{<stuff>}`), since a first-line `\kill` is provided (as opposed to `\\[-\baselineskip]`) to prevent the first line from being typeset. This ensures that the actual tabbing typesetting starts in the first row.

The advantage here is that you can format your code the way you want, without any special package "interrupting" your style or other preferences. Given your example, here is what I would do (without using `\multicol`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}% For length calculations
\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylen}%
\setlength{\mylen}{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\mylen}
  \begin{tabbing}
    \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \kill
    \textbf{program} test \> \> \> \> \texttt{some text here} \\
    \textbf{var} \\
    \> $i$ : \textbf{integer}; \> \> \> \texttt{...} \\
    \> $b$ : \textbf{boolean}; \\
    \textbf{begin} \\
    \> $i:=1$; \> \> \> \texttt{...} \\
    \> $b:=\texttt{true}$; \\
    \> \textbf{while} $i<15$ \textbf{do} \\
    \> \> $i:=i+1$; \\
    \> \> $b:=\textbf{not}\ b$; \> \> \texttt{some text here} \\
    \> \textbf{od} \\
    \textbf{end}
  \end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX tabbing example]

---

## `verbatim`

The `verbatim` environment is a paragraph-making environment that gets LaTeX to print exactly what you type in. It turns LaTeX into a typewriter with carriage returns and blanks having the same effect that they would on a typewriter. The output looks exactly as it looks in the input file. Typical typesetting in `verbatim` would resemble

```
\begin{verbatim}
  <stuff> 
\end{verbatim}
```

or

```
\begin{verbatim*}
  <stuff>
\end{verbatim*}
```

where the difference between `verbatim` and `verbatim*` is that the latter prints spaces as "visual" spaces, i.e., a short, squat "u". Inline `verbatim` is also possible using

```
\verb char literal_text char
```

or

```
\verb*char literal_text char
```

with a similar meaning as before for the unstarred and starred versions. There may be no space between `\verb` or `\verb*` and `char` (space is shown here only for clarity). Here `char` denotes the `\verb` delimiters and should match at the start and end. `char` can be anything except a space (or a `*` for the `\verb` form).

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution? My programs are generally short and I do not have too many...

Comment: Well... i have no other choice... thank you...

Comment: Do you know how to add a frame around this code, and may I use `\caption` and `\label` to make it a reference?

Comment: @SoftTimur: I've updated my answer to show how to frame a code segment using `tabbing`. If you want to use `\caption` and `\label`, you can put the entire `tabbing` environment in a float of your own choice. Create your own using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: I suggest to use the `listings` package because it's very easy and fast to use

Comment: @Spike I wouldn't use `listings` for pseudocode, though.

Answer (score 7):

The `minted` package uses the Pygments Python module as a backend to produce highlighted (and even colored) code in LaTeX.

You can get your own language supported by writing a new Pygment module. See [this blog post](http://www.raphink.info/2011/03/syntax-highlighting-in-latex.html) for example.

To write comments to the right of the code, you could probably use a `minipage`.

Comment: The link is broken; try http://ctan.org/pkg/minted

Answer (score 0):

I lately found the `algpseudocodex` [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex) combining nicely the features of `algorithmicx` and the lean layout of `algorithm2e`.