# Pseudocode, special formatting

Tags: formatting, pseudocode

I want to write an algorithm in LaTeX. It's not any programming language, it is pseudocode with a very mathematical style. Furthermore it is divided in a main function and some subfunctions. I also would like to be able to comment (almost) every line to describe what it is used for.

As an example, you may want to take a look at this link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.3496&rep=rep1&type=pdf

See page 10 for the code. I would like to write it in the very same style if this is somehow possible.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you show us some attempt you've made in achieving this layout? Is there something in particular you're struggling with? Some popular packages for code formatting are `listings`, `fancyvrb` and `minted`. There are plenty of questions about them on tex.sx that you can check out.

Comment: So far, I have only used listings. The main problem is the structure of the example, how it is split up in the different (sub)functions in one table

Comment: There are many options that vary across styles and ease-of-use. Here is a list of options in terms of typesetting algorithms in pseudocode that may be of interest: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429)

Comment: Have you read http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=algorithms ?