# Problems with formatting LaTeX document pseudo code, ending while loops

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I am writing a LaTeX document for some pseudo code I have written. I have a bunch of while loops, but the way latex is formatting them, it looks like:

```
while(x)
   while(y)
      while(z)
```

whereas I want it to do:

```
while(x)
   while(y)
while(z)
```

so I tried using `\endwhile`, and got the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.44    \ENDWHILE
```

I am using

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{program}
```

after using [wikibooks - Algorithms & Pseudocode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode) site, in which they use `\endwhile`, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possibly related: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, you actually only need *one* of those packages. Pick either one, and it should work.

**Example for `algorithmic`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithmic}
  \WHILE{condition}
    \WHILE{condition}
      \STATE\COMMENT{do something}
    \ENDWHILE
  \ENDWHILE
  \WHILE{condition}
    \STATE\COMMENT{do something else}
  \ENDWHILE
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

**Example for `program`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}
  \begin{program} 
  \WHILE condition \DO 
    \WHILE condition \DO 
      \COMMENT{do something}
    \OD
  \OD
  \WHILE condition \DO 
    \COMMENT{do something else}
  \OD
  \end{program}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that uses algorithmic, not algorithm... Now it is working.  I definately like algorithmic more than program, so thank you.  I was going off of that website.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I misread that in your post, sorry. `algorithm` only adds the float environments, so with `algorithm` and `algorithmic` you should be fine: `\begin{algorithm}\begin{algorithmic}...\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, it turns out that you need to have while-do statements

```
while{x} \DO
 a,b,c = z
 while{z} \DO
  z = 1 \OD
\OD
while{y} \DO
 y += 1 \OD
```

That seemed to fix the indentation problem for me.