# Aligning pseudocode in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, algorithms, code

My algorithms class is following strict guidelines for pseudocode. Let's say I have something like the following:

```
y = 0
for i = n downto 0
    y = a_i + x * y
```

I want this to appear left-aligned on the page and have line numbering. The `algorithmic` package seems close to what I want, but it doesn't follow my class's pseudocode conventions. Is there a really simple way to hack this in to LaTeX?

I am just learning LaTeX, so I apologize if this is a simple question.

Comment: You might be interested in: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you and I was **absolutely** sure that the algorithmic package is not the way to go, I'd use something like this:

```
\begin{align*}
  &y = 0 \\
  &\text{for $i = n$ downto 0} \\
  & \hspace{1cm} y = a_i + x * y
\end{align*}
```

This results in

[image: rendering of the above LaTeX snippet]

Comment: So after trying the other packages listed here, I've found too many issues. This one seems to be the best for code and embedding some math (as I will need this later). Thanks for the answers, everyone.

Answer (score 6):

I have never used an algorithm package in Latex, what I'd do is use the `verbatim` environment and manually indent the code in the text editor.

```
\begin{verbatim}
1 y=0
2 for i = n downto 0
3     y = a_i + x * y
\end{verbatim}
```

This will put exactly what you type in the environment in the output, including whitespace. If you need fancy Latex (like subscript and such) check the `alltt` package.

[Info on Verbatim](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Verbatim_Text)

Answer (score 3):

Edit 2: Sorry, from your code excerpt and another answer, I somehow thought you wanted verbatim text.

I have had success using `algorithmicx`. It is customizable for your needs.

[Documentation (PDF)](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $y \gets 0$
\For{$i \gets n, 0$}
  \State $y \gets a_i + xy$
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example algorithm.}
\label{examplealgorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

Edit 1: Looking through some of my old reports, here are two example customizations for the `Verbatim` environment. See the documentation PDF (link below) for more details.

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small,
   frame=single, rulecolor=\color{blue}, framerule=0.5mm, framesep=1mm, 
   xleftmargin=2mm}
%\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\scriptsize, 
   %numbers=left, numbersep=8pt, baselinestretch=1, xleftmargin=5mm, 
   %commandchars=\~\{\}}

\begin{Verbatim}
y = 0
for i = n downto 0
    y = a_i + x * y
\end{Verbatim}
```

---

Original: I recommend the `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` package, not to be confused with the built-in `verbatim` environment. It does exactly what you need.

[Documentation. (PDF)](https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/doc/fancyvrb-doc.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly what you want you could use the [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/),

[image: listings output]

or the [`algorithms package`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/)

[image: algorithms output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,%
    }%

\lstset{emph={%
    downto, for%
    },emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries\underbar}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
y = 0
for i = n downto 0
    y = a_i + x * y
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The first `lstset` above sets the options in terms of the background color, the font family and what kind of numbering to use.

Add any keywords you want highlighted in the second `lstset`, or comment this out if you don't want that. Or add additional `lstset` if you want different groups of words highlighted differently.

If you need the code to by typeset then you can use the `algorithmic` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\downto}{\to}% Select what you want to use for this
\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{}% Since you don't want the DO at end of FOR
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]% Number every line
\FOR{$i = n \downto 0$}
    \STATE $y = a_i + x * y$
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the **end for** you can use `\renewcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{}`

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster doesn't mention what exactly are the problems with `algorithmic` ("it doesn't follow my class's pseudocode conventions"), it is hard to be more precise.

Trying to infer *what* may not be your conventions, it seems that you don't want the **end if**, **end for**, etc parts and that's what's the [`[noend]`](https://github.com/rbrito/algorithms/blob/master/algorithms.dtx#L588) option (when loading the package, as in `\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}`) is for: it lets you save vertical space, which is especially important for submitting papers with strict page limits.

I would recommend that you increase the default horizontal indentation from `1em` to, say, `2em` if you omit the end markers. You can use `\algsetup{indent=2em}` at any time or pass the `indent=2em` option when loading the package.