# Print programs with automatically generated line numbers and tabbing

Tags: spacing, highlighting, code, tabbing

I have post a question several weeks ago: [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax), and I choose to use `tabbing` package at the moment.

Now I really need to keep the tabbing and print a line number before each line. It will be great if this line number is automatically generated. Does anyone know how to do it?

I guess one fundamental approach is to define my own highlighting and tabbing rules based on the syntax of my language. (I have seen an example somewhere, but I could not find it anymore...) Could anyone help?

Comment: It would be helpful to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: IMHO you made the wrong choice to use `tabbing` and now want automatic line number and syntax highlighting that other packages like [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) can perform by *default*. Why do you "really *need* to keep [..] `tabbing`"?

Comment: I'm with Werner. This sounds to me like the ideal use case for listings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package [**ntabbing**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntabbing) on CTAN which provides the `ntabbing` environment which numbers lines. It's not present on TeX Live, but it's simple to put it in the same directory as the main file.