# How do you add a comment to pseudocode in LaTeX?

Tags: algorithms, comments, pseudocode

Is there a special formatting to add comments to code? I mean I want to show comments in pseudocode that I write in LaTeX.

```
this is code // this is comment part (the part that I want)
```

Edit: To be more clear, what I mean is in "algorithmic" syntax I write some pseudo code. However, I am not sure if there is a standard comment used in that context.

Comment: To clarify the question, please compose a small [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Although this does not specifically address comments, if you are still trying to choose which package to use, an excellent summary is available at: [print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429)

Answer (score 26):

Since you use the term `algorithmic`, I assume you're using the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which provides the `algorithmic` package and environment). Then the `\COMMENT{...}` macro typesets a comment in pseudo-code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \STATE this is code \COMMENT{this is a comment}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}​
```

If you're using the (more advanced) [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (and use `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`, which also provides an `algorithmic` environment), then the `\Comment{...}` macro typesets a comment in pseudo-code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State this is code \Comment{this is a comment}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}​
```

In both these environments/packages, you are able to modify the formatting (or typesetting) of the comment. Alternatively, you could create your own `\comment{...}` macro as well, based on the existing commenting macros.

Answer (score 12):

You can use also `\tcp{...}` to add comments in `algorithm2e` environment.

Comment: `algorithm2e` is not `algorithmic` from the `alogrithms` bundle, so I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you! This actually solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I [found](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=6113) next possibilities:

1. Tab characters seem to work even in flexible columns.
2. `escapechar=\%` in options will turn on escape to LaTeX. Then, using `%\mbox[2in][r]{comment}%` should work, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
\tcc{the comment}
```

Example Latex code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm 1 title}
\tcc{the comment}
\end{algorithm}
```

How it should be rendered:

[image: Rendered Latex]