# Good way to "ensure" a return value

Tags: algorithms

I want to describe an algorithm, which is not changing a given input but it is producing a new element:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
...
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $\mathcal{P} \subset F[X_1 \dots X_{k-1 }][X_k]$
\ENSURE % something about the return value
\RETURN $\operatorname{Elim}_{X_k}(\mathcal{P})$
\end{algorithmic}
```

Ensure is not quite the thing I'm looking for because I want to make a statemanent about the output which does not have its own name.

Another thing is that I want to name the algorithm and lateron call it. I know that the algorithm does not to anthing different than call the function Elim but  I want to underline the difference between the existence of a mathematical function and the algorithm (e.g. I don't want to discuss the computional complexity of a mathematical function).

Any ideas?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there is no requirement to use the commands provided by the [`algorithms` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) - you can define your own.

In the minimal example below I've defined `\OUTPUT` which typesets **Output:** just like **Ensure:** and **Require:** (actually as an `\item`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\OUTPUT}{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $\mathcal{P} \subset F[X_1 \dots X_{k-1 }][X_k]$
\OUTPUT Here is a statement about the output.
\RETURN $\operatorname{Elim}_{X_k}(\mathcal{P})$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

I would suggest using the more advanced [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). Or, for a more general view on alternatives to the above, see [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429).