# Print programs with its proper syntax by minted

Tags: spacing, highlighting, minted, code

I have post a question several weeks ago: [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax), and I finally decided to use the package `minted`.

I summarize a little bit my needs here: the language I define has its special tokens (`do`, `od`, `if`, `fi`...), and support comments. I would like `minted` to highlight these key words (coloring is not necessary at this stage). If possible, I hope `minted` could read a program directly from a file.

@Raphink showed me [a blog post](http://www.raphink.info/2011/03/syntax-highlighting-in-latex.html) for example, which is too hard to understand for me without the output picture; the doc of `minted` does not contain any details either...

Does anyone have any idea about my specific requests above?

Comment: The blog you are referencing *does* have an output picture. If it is a specific language that you need to support (and Pygments does not yet have it in its list of lexers) then this is not so much a LaTeX related problem, as it is a Pygments one. In that case you would have to [write your own lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/). Pygments supports like 150 languages though, so what you are working with would have to be pretty obscure for it not to be listed.

Comment: The question looks like it is about Pygments to me, so it's off-topic for us.