# Environment code undefined

Tags: verbatim, code

Why do I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment code undefined.` when I use:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4wide]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}  

\begin{code}  

module Dir where

import TeX
import Data.List

\end{code}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{7cm}

\begin{code}

module DirV where

import TeX
import Data.List

\end{code}

\end{minipage}
```

[image: With code]

[image: With verbatim]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please expand your code to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). If you're not loading any packages, this is just natural, because -- as the message says -- there is no `code` environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have an environment called `code`. If you are trying to print code, you might be interested in the `verbatim` environment, or other pretty-printing environments/packages. See [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764).

Wrapping your code snippet into a minimal compiling document using `verbatim`, it produces the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}%
\begin{verbatim}
module Dir where

import TeX
import Data.List
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{7cm}%
\begin{verbatim}
module DirV where

import TeX
import Data.List
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `listings` package should also be mentioned here. It provides syntax highlighting and a lot of other features for code.

Comment: It doesnt have the same format of `\begin{code}` but it works just fine, thanks for the tip mate

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I've referenced [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764) which provides a host of code formatting packages, including [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

Comment: @seph: What "format of `\begin{code}`" are you referring to? If you could post an image of the format you're after, one might be able to provide a duplicate environment that suits your needs. You can do so via an [edit to your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/41286/edit).

Comment: @seph: The `verbatim` environment seems to match your specification on p 4, while that of p 1 is something entirely different.

Comment: yeah, the one on p1 is an environment that i get using the `\begin{code}`