# Review of algorithm-related packages?

Tags: listings, best-practices, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax)

Where can I find (if it exists) an updated review of the most relevant packages for handling with algorithms (pseudocode or *code* programs)?

I know about <strike>`algorithms`</strike> [see edit below], that seems to be the most complete and suitable to my case, but anyway I would like to know more alternatives.

Please, notice that this is *not* a question about *"which is the best tool..."*. I just wondered if there exists a good and updated review on that subject.

---

EDIT: In fact, I was wrong about my initial decision. The package I found the most useful in my case was `listings`.

Comment: I recommend `algorithm2e` because it's very compatible and produces good output. See the Algorithms and Listings presentation on http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html for more background.

Comment: A good summary is available at [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax).