# algorithm2e indentation / line break

Tags: indentation, algorithm2e

I have the following problem: I am writing a couple of algorithms using algorithm2e. I have a bunch of longer if statements and longer if conditions.
The lines are broken, but the new lines are not indented properly:

```
\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwInput{Parameters...}

    \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}

    \If{the lines through $x_{1}, x_{2}$ and $y_{1}, y_{2}$ intersect in a single point $z$
        which lies on the circle $C$
       }
    {
      Do something \;
    }
    \caption{Algoritm test...}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I could force line breaks at certain positions using \, but that does not fix the indentation problems either. I saw the solution provided here: [How to break lines in conditions using algorithm2e?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101021/how-to-break-lines-in-conditions-using-algorithm2e)

But I don't understand what is happening in that code and I was not able to reproduce the result with my problem. How can I indent the code correctly (is it possible to use something like an mbox?)?

Comment: Have you tried to use 'mbox' command?

Comment: Obviously, but without achieving the desired effect...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That is the one that OP commented on. You answered this question any got checked, so what is the deal now?

Comment: @Symbol1 I posted the same thing as in the linked answer. As I wrote in the second line, I just wanted to clarify what the OP wants. As the problem is solved now, but there is no new information at all, we can close. I could even delete my answer. Don't know. Do you want me to retract it? Do you think others will benefit from this?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi (that is a quick comment.) Now I see that you answered **1 hr ago** and got checked within. So it seems OP is like "whatever things cannot be better"...

Comment: @Symbol1 I had the same feeling :-). Well, I converted my answer to community as I stole the main part from the dupe. And as I do not want to get accused for rep-baiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101023. If this is what you want, we should close as duplicate. If not, you have to explain better, what you want, what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input} % just a guess
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output} % just a guess
\usepackage{showframe} % for demonstration
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \SetAlgoLined
        \KwInput{Parameters...}     
        \KwOutput{$\emptyset$}
        \If{the lines through $x_{1}, x_{2}$ and $y_{1}, y_{2}$ intersect in a single point $z$ which lies\\
            \mbox{}\phantom{\textbf{if}} on the circle $C$
        }
        {
            Do something;
        }
        \caption{Algoritm test...}
    \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

[image]