# Formatting in Latex - Pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am trying to create a kind of pseudocode in Latex resembling the one shown below [image].

What I tried is:

```
1. Convert R to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$\\

2. Assume N is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.\\

3. If N is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$, then\\

            \begin{center}
            $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$\\
            Repeat the procedure from step 1
            \end{center}
   Else

            \begin{center}
            $\theta = \theta_{0}$
            \end{center}
   End
```

Its not turning out like I want though. Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: You're probably interested in [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764).

Comment: could you please provide a working solution to the pseudocode above? its urgent :(

Comment: Please use proper tags for your questions ;-) none of the ones you used had something to do with the question …

Comment: I am sorry. I am totally new to latex and tex.stackexchange

Comment: could anyone please provide a working solution?

Comment: Don't cross-post. Rather flag for moderator attention and request migration, or delete and re-post.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. …

Comment: … Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: I created a solution :)

Comment: Most of us would say that egreg did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “hand made” solution reproducing the layout you showed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{pseudocode}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[pseudocode,1]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[pseudocode,2]{label={},ref=\arabic*,nosep}

\begin{document}

\begin{pseudocode}
\item\label{step:convert} Convert $R$ to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$.

\item Assume $N$ is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.

\item If $N$ is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$, then
    \begin{pseudocode}
    \item $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$
    \item Repeat the procedure from step \ref{step:convert}
    \end{pseudocode}
  Else
    \begin{pseudocode}
    \item $\theta = \theta_{0}$
    \end{pseudocode}
  End
\end{pseudocode}
where $\Delta\theta$, $\beta$ are two constants.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS!!! Just a small editing I had to do: placing \label{step:convert} at the end of the line :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\LinesNumbered% Number algorithm lines
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{$R$, $\beta$}
  \KwResult{$\theta_0$}
  Convert~$R$ to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$\; \label{first_step}
  Assume~$N$ is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within~$F_l$ and~$F_r$\;
  \eIf{\text{$N$ is larger than a predefined threshold~$\beta$}}{
    $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$\;
    Repeat the procedure from Step~\ref{first_step}\;
  }{
    $\theta = \theta_{0}$\;
  }  
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `{enumerate}` and the normal equation environments (`{equation}` and `{gather}` in this case – the `*` prevents numbering). The `fleqn` document class option sets the equations left aligned; omit this options to center them.

[image: easy pseudo code]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Convert R to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$
\item Assume N is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.
\item If N is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$, then
    \begin{gather*}
    \theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta\\
    \text{Repeat the procedure from step 1}
    \end{gather*}
    Else
    \begin{equation*}
    \theta = \theta_{0}
    \end{equation*}
    End
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

More information can be found in the package manuals and LaTeX beginners books ;-)

Comment: Not enough reputation to vote it up :(
But my solution works smoothly as well :)
Thanks!!!

Comment: This however globally modifies the placement of math displays.

Answer (score 1):

BINGO!!! I created a solution! Works like a charm :)
Remember to use: `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Convert R to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$\\

\State Assume N is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$\\

\If {$N \textgreater \beta$}
    \State $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$
    \State Repeat the procedure from step 1
\Else
    \State $\theta = \theta_{0}$
\EndIf

\end {algorithmic}
```

Comment: Instead of saying remember to include blank, you could instead complete your MWE.

Comment: MWE? I am not sure I understood what u mean...i just posted my solution...its working fine. Might help somebody else :)

Comment: Here is the canned message for MWE click the links to read up on it: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: +1 for a newcomer answering his/her own question. Edit it now so that someone can cut out your code, paste it and have it compile. (It's wonderful sometimes how urgency can beget creativity.)