# algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am confused about the packages for writing simple "algorithms". There are too many options, and it is confusing when to use what. For example, if I use `algpseudocode`, then I can't add `algorithmic` because it is already included in the `algorithm` package.

Is there any definitive guidelines for a streamlined approach?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: `algpseudocode` is part of the `algorithmicx` bundle, it gives you an improved version of `algorithmic` besides providing some other features.

Comment: Related: [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764)

Comment: For those finding this question on google nowadays, there's also a good resource here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Algorithms

Answer (score 363, accepted):

## TL;DR version:

- **algorithm** - float wrapper for algorithms.
- **algorithmic** - first algorithm typesetting environment.
- **algorithmicx** - second algorithm typesetting environment.
- **algpseudocode** - layout for `algorithmicx`.
- **algorithm2e** - third algorithm typesetting environment.

I use `algorithmicx` with `algpseudocode` since they are superior to `algorithmic`. I think `algorithmicx` offers the same functionality compared to `algorithm2e`, but I find its syntax clearer than the one provided by `algorithm2e`.

## Detailed version

### algorithm

Float wrapper for algorithms. It is similar to block commands `table` or `figure`, which you wrap around your table/figure to give it a number and to prevent it being split over two pages. The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) says:

> When placed within the text without being encapsulated in a floating
> environment `algorithmic` environments may be split over a page
> boundary, greatly detracting from their appearance. In addition, it is
> useful to have algorithms numbered for reference and for lists of
> algorithms to be appended to the list of contents. The `algorithm`
> environment is meant to address these concerns by providing a floating
> environment for algorithms.

Example:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm caption}
    \label{alg:algorithm-label}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        ... Your pseudocode ...
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

### algorithmic

This is the environment in which you write your pseudocode. You have predefined commands for common structures such as `if`, `while`, `procedure`. All the commands are capitalized, e.g. `\IF{cond} ... \ELSE ...`. The documentation[1](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) says:

> The `algorithmic` environment provides an environment for describing
> algorithms and the `algorithm` environment provides a “float” wrapper
> for algorithms (implemented using `algorithmic` or some other method at
> the users’s option). The reason for two environments being provided is
> to allow the user maximum flexibility.

Example:

```
\begin{algorithmic}
    \IF{some condition is true}
        \STATE do some processing
    \ELSIF{some other condition is true}
        \STATE do some different processing
    \ELSE
        \STATE do the default actions
    \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
```

---

### algorithmicx

This package is like `algorithmic` upgraded. It enables you to define custom commands, which is something  `algorithmic` can't do. So if you don't want to write your (crazy) custom commands, you will be fine with `algorithmic`. You use `algorithmicx` the same way you use `algorithmic`, only the syntax and details are slightly different. See the example below for details. The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) says:

> The package algorithmicx itself doesn’t define any algorithmic
> commands, but gives a set of macros to define such a command set. You
> may use only algorithmicx, and define the commands yourself, or you
> may use one of the predefined command sets

Example:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] % The number tells where the line numbering should start
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$} \Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
            \State $r\gets a \bmod b$
            \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
                \State $a \gets b$
                \State $b \gets r$
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
            \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
            \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

### algpseudocode

This is just a layout for `algorithmicx` which tries to be as simillar as possible to `algorithmic`. There are also other layouts, such as:

1. `algcompatible` (fully compatible with the algorithmic package),
2. `algpascal` (aims to create a formatted pascal program, you can transform a pascal program into an `algpascal` algorithm description with some basic substitution rules).
3. `algc` (just like the algpascal, but for c. This layout is incomplete).

The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) says:

> If you are familiar with the algorithmic package, then you’ll find it
> easy to switch. You can use the old algorithms with the
> `algcompatible` layout, but please use the `algpseudocode` layout for
> new algorithms. To use `algpseudocode`, simply use
> `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`. **You don’t need to manually load the
> `algorithmicx` package, as this is done by `algpseudocode`.**

See the example for `algorithmicx`, it uses the `algpseudocode` layout.

---

### algorithm2e

This is another algorithm environment just like `algorithmic` or `algorithmicx`. The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) says:

> Algorithm2e is an environment for writing algorithms in LaTeX2e. An
> `algorithm` is defined as floating object like figures. It provides
> macros that allow you to create different sorts of key words, thus a
> set of predefined key words is given. You can also change the
> typography of the keywords.

Example:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
        read current\;
        \eIf{understand}{
            go to next section\;
            current section becomes this one\;
            }{
            go back to the beginning of current section\;
        }
    }
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: A lovely, detailed answer!  It sounds like the TL;DRTL;DR version is:  "use `algorithmicx`"?  Your discussion is very clear about why, and whether, to prefer `algorithmicx` to `algorithmic`, but doesn't offer much comparison to `algorithm2e`.  Is that because you are less familiar with it, because it is well known to be inferior, or something else?

Comment: Yes, you are right: I am not very familiar with `algorithm2e`. I think they should offer similar functionality, but I prefer the syntax of `algorithmicx`. I edited my answer to make it clear that it is only my (subjective) preference.

Comment: Even if you load `algorithmicx` I understand you still have to load `algorithm` too?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Extensive answer! For a quick decision it may be helpful to include pictures the compiled outputs for each package

Comment: When I read the section about `algorithmicx`, I didn't immediately get that `algpseudocode` should also be loaded in order to use the package. Maybe I'm the only one who experienced that, otherwise it could maybe be added somewhere.

Comment: It would be nicer if you could write draft an algorithm and the same psuedocode using every package to see how easy/hard every one is to use.

Comment: A "layouts" are "predefined command sets". `algorithmicx` itself does not define e.g. if statements, etc. Note that multiple layouts can be used within the same document, by using `\alglanguage{<layoutname>}`.

Comment: The layout names are not exactly obvious. e.g. the layout corresponding to `algcompatible` is `algorithmic` You can look for e.g. `\algnewlanguage{algorithmic}` in the `.sty` files:  https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx

Comment: can we use `else if` inside algorithmicx?

Answer (score 11):

- I found the recent [`algpseudocodex` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex) to be a good step towards a unification of the variety of `algorithm*` packages.
- That package combines nicely some features (e.g. genericity, templating) of `algorithmicx` and the lean layout of `algorithm2e`, that is, the vertical scope lines.

[image]
*(Example is taken from the manual.)*

Comment: Hello. Thanks for sharing. I don't think that `algorithm2e` is hard to use: it uses a C-like syntax easy to learn. The main drawback of `algorithm2e` is that it uses floating environments...

Comment: +1: I re-formatted your answer a bit, hope that's ok.

Comment: @projetmbc Thx for mentioning. True, I modified my explanation. @Kuehner: Great, thx! I just removed the quoted `forest` as I am not referring to a LaTeX package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @projetmbc, it seems you can disable floating with `algorithm2e` by using `[H]` option.