# Environment for comparing algorithms

Tags: tables, algorithms, highlighting, comparison

I am aware of different environments to type algorithms in pseudocode (see f.i. [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229355/algorithm-algorithmic-algorithmicx-algorithm2e-algpseudocode-confused))

Is there any environment that would simplify creating such overviews where different algorithms are presented side by side, as in the article on Robot Skill Learning by [Stulp & Sigaud (2013)](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pjbr.2013.4.issue-1/pjbr-2013-0003/pjbr-2013-0003.xml):

[image: result]

Here clearly some editorial work has been done by the journal, but the basics probably was some kind of table environment that allows highlighting rows.

Comment: You could use TikZ. But please ask more detailed and less broad and show us, what you've done.