# \crefrange{} links to the right line in the wrong algorithm

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have a bunch of algorithms which I need to explain by referring to certain line numbers in them. I'm trying to use `\crefrange` for this, but the simplest example seems to fail.

In the example below, on the 2nd page, I refer to line range 1-3 in the 2nd algorithm using `\crefrange`. Unfortunately, in the resulting PDF, when I click on "Lines 1-3," the link takes me to the right line but in the wrong algorithm (i.e., algorithm one, not two.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Page 1}
\cref{a:one:line2} in \cref{a:one} is \dots

\cref{a:one:line2,a:one:line3} of the algorithm are based on \dots
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Baseline}\label{a:one}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Do X 
  \State Do Y        \label{a:one:line2}
  \State $x = y + z$ \label{a:one:line3}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\pagebreak

\section{Page 2}
\cref{a:two:line2} in \cref{a:two} is \dots

\crefrange{a:two:line1}{a:two:line3} of the algorithm are based on \dots
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Baseline}\label{a:two}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State Do X        \label{a:two:line1}
        \State Do Y        \label{a:two:line2}
        \State $x = y + z$ \label{a:two:line3}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I'm using TexStudio with `pdflatex` on Ubuntu, if that matters.

Comment: You also get the warning `l.30         \State
                    Do Y        \label{a:two:line2}pdfTeX warning (ext4): desti
nation with the same identifier (name{ALG@line.3}) has been already used, dupli
cate ignored`, right?

Comment: I can confirm that the issue arises not only with `\crefrange` but with `\cref` as well.

Comment: Yes, getting that warning and similar ones for `ALG@line.2`, `ALG@line.1`.

Comment: algorithm is not among the supported packages, see section 13 of the cleveref package.

Comment: Page 30 here (http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) says _"Added
support for `algorithm` package"_. And page 24 says `algorithmic` is not supported, which I'm not using am I? I am only doing `\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}`

Comment: It lists the supported packages and also explicitly mentions some that are not supported, but this does not mean that all the other packages are supported.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to rewrite my algorithms into something supported by not-so-cleverref :(

Comment: @Alin Tomescu Your comment is clever, but misguided ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `cleveref` together with `hyperref`, if you see the "`destination with the same identifier has already been used, duplicate ignored`" warning in the log, a work-around that often works is to disable hypertexnames in hyperref:

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

Setting this option in your MWE produces correct hyperlinks for me.

Most instances of this issue were fixed in `cleveref` some years ago, and this work-around shouldn't be necessary. The `algorithm`, `algorithmicx` and `algorithm2e` packages are all supported by `cleveref` (see below for more details). Looks like there's a bad interaction between `cleveref`'s `algorithmicx` and `hyperref` support, which needs fixing in `cleveref`.

The `algorithm` package just provides a separate floating environment for algorithms. The only support required is to provide a default name (and translations thereof) for these algorithm environments, which `cleveref` does. The `algorithmicx` package provides a framework for typesetting the actual algorithms. You usually load a companion layout package that styles the algorithms for you (which internally loads the `algorithmicx` package), rather than loading the `algorithmicx` package itself. `algpseudocode` is the most commonly used of these `algorithmicx` layout packages. `cleveref` supports the `algorithmicx` framework, hence all its layout packages like `algpseudocode`. The `algorithmicx` package is by-and-large a better drop-in replacement for `algorithmic` package (which is why the latter isn't supported by `cleveref`). The `algorithm2e` package is an alternative to `algorithmicx`. See [this stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230789/27827) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: Yes, this seems to fix the minimal working example, but in my project I use `acmart.cls` which imports `hyperref` with different options so I get an `Option clash for package hyperref` error. But I will figure out a way to fix... Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a `\PassOptionsToPackage{hypertexnames=false}{hyperref}`
before the `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}` did it. Thank you again! :)