# A simple way to typeset preformatted text blocks or pseudocode

Tags: formatting, verbatim, algorithms

A am looking for a package or a simple method for typesetting blocks of pseudocode or just pre-formatted text.  I know about the multitude of packages for [typesetting algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355), but all I need is a way to control the indentation and line breaks.  Being able to mark indented blocks with a vertical line would be nice too (this one is done with *algorithm2e*):
[image]

I do not want to use an extra level of indirection by defining LaTeX commands for all pseudocode terms I am going to use (`\If`, `\While`, `\ExtractNextElementFrom`, etc), I want to write algorithms as plain nested prose.

It should also be possible to use basic formatting (like emphasis) and math mode inside.

I would also like to be able to strip an equal amount of indentation from all lines (to distinguish source indentation from the layout indentation).

I am currently wondering if I can achieve this with some tabulating environment, or by defining my own environment for inserting an indented block inside another indented block...  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

No vertical lines but simple to set up:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{zzz}{\@vobeyspaces\obeylines}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{zzz}
if \textbf{this}
  set $x$ to $y^2$
else
  if \textbf{that}
    while $z <0$ do
      something
    end
  fi
fi
\end{zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Could you provide some links to the documentation of `\@vobeyspaces`, `\obeylines`, and maybe other relevant links, please?

Comment: `\obeylines` is documented in the texbook, `\@vobeyspaces`  is a version of `\obeyspaces` in the latex format, both are used in the definition of the standard `verbatim` environment, so `texdoc source2e`

Comment: Though, i wonder how to strip some equal amount of indentation from all lines.  I will edit the question.

Comment: @Alexey set `\leftskip` to some possibly negative value in the definition of zzz

Comment: Can i automatically detect the current width of one space, to negate a specific number of spaces?

Comment: @Alexey `\fontdimen2\font`  is the width of a space in the current font