# latex adds =0 at the end of algorithm

Tags: algorithms

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my algorithm code? it adds =0 at the end when I run it. this is the algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
‎\usepackage{algorithmic}‎‎
‎\usepackage{algpseudocode}‎

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}                    
\caption{Dynamic programming algorithm for RRH clustering problem}      
\label{alg1}                          
\begin{algorithmic}[1]   ‎
\STATE return table[N,Capacity]‎‎
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}\end{document}‎
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `latin` environment?

Comment: thanks, I was writing farsi so I needed this latin package. I forgot to remove it from here.

Comment: @user3223551 Please, make the snippet into a compilable (minimal) document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that still shows the issue.

Comment: when I write this minimal version it does not add the =0 and works fine. but in my own article, it adds it. its the same code!

Comment: Then this is what you have to do: Make a copy of the TeX file. Start deleting stuff until the problem goes away. Undelete the last bit you deleted. Your problem is there, somehow. Keep on deleting other stuff that does not affect it, until you're down to a minimal example (more or less). Instead of deleting, at first it may be easier to comment out stuff, so your actions are easily reversed. A bisecting method is very useful to speed this up. (Start by deleting everything *after* the trouble spot. Try putting the troubled code at the top of the document to save time.)

Comment: Instead of commenting out, surrounding blocks of code by `\iffalse` … `\fi` is quicker. Anyhow, I expect the problem is some code, somewhere, assigning zero to a counter, except the name of the counter got gobbled by other code. This might be caused by different packages interfering with each others' code, for example.

Comment: I did this, the problem was the ‎\usepackage{algpseudocode}‎ part. when I remove it, the code works fine

Comment: please fix the example so that it generates the error. (You could post an answer yourself as well) or delete the question. As it stands no one other than you can see the problem or fix it.

Comment: I added the package that was causing the problem to the question

Comment: @user3223551: Unrelated to the issue, but please note that your example is not compilable with the april 2018 release of LaTeX (which uses utf8 as standard input encoding). Your code contains several invisible characters: (U+200E, left-to-right-mark) in the beginning and end of the line`\usepackage{algorithmic}` as well as after `[N,Capacity]`.

Comment: Apart from the U+200E problem, the example doesn't compile: you can't load both `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode`; the command `\STATE` is for the former, so I removed the latter. No issue at all. Even if I change `\STATE return table[N,Capacity]` into `\RETURN table[N,Capacity]` the output is as expected. I believe the issue has something to do with bidirectional text. Please make a *real* example that shows the issue.

Comment: If one removes all the U+200E characters from the example and tries to compile it, one recieves the error message ' Command \algorithmic already defined.' If one now has a look at the pdf file that is produced by this unsucessful compilation, one can see the described `=0` that is added after `[N,Capacity]`. To conclude: Never rely on the 'output'  of a compilation that yielded an error message.

Comment: For a summary on packages that can be useful for displaying algorithms, you might also want to have a look here: [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/134144)