# How to format the algorithm

Tags: formatting, algorithms

I have the text for the following algorithm, but I am unable to format it, with the numbers and spacing as in the image:

[image]

```
$COVERABILITY-GRAPH((S,T,F,M_0))$\\
$(V,E,v_0):=(\{M_0\},\emptyset,M_0);$\\
Work:set:=$\{M_0\}$\\
\textbf{while} Work $\neq \emptyset$\\
\textbf{do} select $M$ from Work;\\
Work:=Work$\setminus\{M\};$\\
\textbf{for} $t\in$enabled(M)\\
\textbf{do} $M':=$fire($M,t);$\\
$M':=$AddOmegas($M,t,M',V,E$)\;\
\textbf{if} $M'\not \in V$\\
\textbf{then} $V:=V\cup \{M'\}$\\
Work:=Work$\cup\{M'\};$\\
$E:=E\cup\{(M,t,M')\}$\\
\textbf{return}$(V,E,v_0)$
```

and also

```
$ADDOMEGAS(M,t,M',V,E)$\\
\textbf{for}$M''\in V$\\
\textbf{do if} $M''<M'$ and $M''\xrightarrow{*}_{E} M$\\
\textbf{then} $M':=M'+((M'-M'').\omega);$\\
\textbf{return} $M';$
```

Comment: You have [several algorithm packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/156344) to do it. No need for e.g. `\textbf{for}`.

Comment: Thanks. I dont see how algorithmic supports numbering

Comment: I am not experienced with any of the packages at all, so I can't be sure of anything. However, I think at least one of them must support numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is the following code, but please see that I leave the exact formatting of the used variables  in your algorithm to you. You did not explain the code, so please check the formatting, for example if `Work` is a variable you can better format it with `\mathit{Work}`.

I used the packages

```
\usepackage{algorithm}% <=================http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% <========== http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
```

Using other packages results in other coding, so please read the documentations (please follow the given links in the comments).

With the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}% <=================http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% <========== http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1] % numbering starts with 1
\Procedure {COVERABILITY-GRAPH}{$S$,$T$,$F$,$M_0$}%                     \Comment{my name is Xyz}
\State $(V,E,v_0):=(\{M_0\},\emptyset,M_0)$ % :=  --> \gets
\State $Work:$ set $:=\{M_0\}$
  \While {$Work \neq \emptyset$}
    \State select $M$ from $Work$
    \State $Work:=Work\setminus\{M\}$
    \For {$t\in$ enabled(M)}
      \State $M':=$ fire($M,t);$
      \State $M':=$ AddOmegas($M,t,M',V,E$)
      \If {$M'\not \in V$}
        \State $V:=V\cup \{M'\}$
      \EndIf
      \State $E:=E\cup\{(M,t,M')\}$
    \EndFor
  \EndWhile
  \State \Return $(V,E,v_0)$
\EndProcedure

\Procedure {ADDOMEGAS}{$M,t,M',V,E$}
  \For {$M''\in V$}
    \If {$M''<M'$ \textbf{and} $M''\rightarrow{*}_{E} M$}
      \State $M':=M'+((M'-M'')\omega)$
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \State \Return $M'$
\EndProcedure
 \caption{COVERABILITY}\label{alg:COVERABILITY}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting alg]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{setspace, etoolbox, caption}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\setstretch{1.25}\let\textbf\textsf\vspace{0.4ex}}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
 \begin{algorithm}
\caption{ \textsc{Coverability-Graph} ($ (S,T,F,M₀) $)}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $(V,E,v₀) ∶= q(\{M₀\},\emptyset,M₀)$;
 \State \textit{Work}: set $ ∶= q\{M₀\}$;
 \While{$ \mathit{Work}\ne\emptyset $}
 \State select $M$ from $\mathit{Work}$;
 \State $\mathit{Work} ∶= q \mathit{Work}∖\{M\}$;
 \For{$t ∈ \mathsf{enabled}(M)$}
 \State $M' ∶= q \mathsf{fire}(M, t)$;
 \State $M' ∶= q \mathsf{AddOmegas}(M, t, M',V, E)$;
 \If{$M' ∉ V$}
 \State $V ∶= q V ∪ \{M'\}$;
 \State $\mathit{Work} ∶= q\mathit{Work} ∪ \{M'\}$;
 \EndIf
 \State $E ∶= q E ∪ \{(M, t, M')\}$;
 \EndFor
 \EndWhile
 \State
 \Return $(V, E, v₀)$;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]