# How to write Rules in Latex

Tags: equations

I want to add some logical rules in my paper

just to avoid confusion, I do not want to build rules

I want to display them in my paper

So I used equations terms

```
\begin{equation}
    $if word = “and” then remove word.$
    \label{Rule1}
\end{equation}
```

I want to see my paper something like this

> if word = “and” then remove word. ................ (1)

How to do it?

Comment: `\begin{equation}` starts math mode, so the two `$`s inside of the `equation` environment will throw errors. It looks like you just started with LaTeX or are using it in a very unelegant manner, so it might be a good idea to read a good and concise introduction to get to know the basic concepts. You could, for example, visit https://www.learnlatex.org/ for this. After you learned basic LaTeX, you might want to take a look at [packages for pseudocode](https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode).

Comment: A short term workaround is to use `\text{}`: `\text{if word} = \text{“and” then remove word.}`.  Also, search this site for "algorithm". To get you started have a look at [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/4301).

Comment: View the list of packages at https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode for a variety of potential packages to use.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, plz post this as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short term *hack* that will achieve the desired results is to use `\text{}`:

[image]

#### Note:

- For a longer term solution, use a package that is specfically designed for algorithms. A good place to start is [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/4301)

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{if word} = \text{``and'' then remove word.}
    \label{Rule1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```