# Type latex for enumerate

Tags: math-mode, bibtex, equations, math-operators, subequations

[image]

Can someone make this enumeration latex?  I really dont understand how can i add space in front of sentence in number 3,4,5,6,7?

Comment: This look like pseudocode more than an enumerate. Please have a look at [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/82917) for some common packages.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the comment that there exist tools for pseudocode, I provide an `enumerate` approach, in case you are forced into such an approach by circumstance.  It makes use of the `tabto` package to manage the indents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,tabto}
\newlength\svloc
\newcommand\indentA{\tabto{40pt}}
\newcommand\saveloc{\tabto*{0pt}\svloc=\TabPrevPos\tabto{\svloc}}
\newcommand\gotoloc{\tabto{\svloc}}
\newcommand\If{\textbf{if}\ }
\newcommand\While{\textbf{while}\ }
\newcommand\Then{\textbf{then}\ }
\newcommand\Else{\textbf{else}\ }
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic{*}),leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=14pt,
  labelsep=4pt,itemindent=18pt,align=left,itemsep=-4pt] 
\item first
\item \While
\item \indentA \If third \saveloc \Then blah
\item \gotoloc \Else blah
\item \indentA Blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]