# Algorithm not formatting correctly

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I'm trying to write an algorithm in latex, but after I put my if statement it gives me back an error and says that there's a missing number. What does that mean? Where is my flaw? This is what I've written (mind you I'm trying to write a generalized algorithm that doesn't necessarily examine things, hence the general statement in if):

```
\For{j = length($y_i$)}{
   \If{$\{x_j$ and $\neg x_j\}$ in $y_i$}{
     \State \text{$a_i$ = F}
        }
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE. Please tell us which document class and which algorithm-related packages you employ.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE. Please provide code which can be compiled as is for reproducing the erroneous behavior/the error-messages. Otherwise things can't be tracked down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up the syntax of `algpseudocode` with that of `algorithm2e`.

With the former package, the syntax is like as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{$j = \operatorname{length}(y_i)$}
   \If{$\{x_j$ and $\neg x_j\}$ in $y_i$}
     \State $a_i = \mathrm{F}$
   \EndIf
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

The latter package has no `\State` command, so I guess you're using `algpseudocode`.

[image]

Note the changes I made to your input to use math mode wherever it's needed.

Comment: Which package of both would you recommend to go with generally?

Comment: @Diaa [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229355/algorithm-algorithmic-algorithmicx-algorithm2e-algpseudocode-confused)