# How to write If not(condition)

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to write the algorithm shown in the picture [image: 1] in latex but I cannot know which package suitable for it either algorithm, or algorithm2e. Beside that the flow itself, I do not know how to write the condition "if not".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For an overview of algorithm packages see: [algorithm, algorithmic, algorithmicx, algorithm2e, algpseudocode = confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229355/123129).

Comment: it is a good overview, but I still cannot figure it out how to write "if not (condition)"!

Comment: Even if you couldn't figure out how to write "if not (condition)", it would have been nice for you to create a MWE with the rest of it.  And for the question to be answerable, you would have needed to pick from one of the 5 algorithm packages mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about this, but you could try

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % remove [ruled] if you like
\SetKwIF{IfNot}{ElseIfNot}{}{if not}{then}{else if not}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \lIfNot{...}{...}
  \lIf{...}{...}

  \uIfNot{A}{
    ...\;
  }\uElseIf{B}{
    ...\;
  }\uElseIfNot{B}{
    ...\;
  }\Else{
    ...\;
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given the multitude of algorithm packages, it would be nice if you would show a short, but compilable document in your answer so people can see which packages etc. you use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question as being specific about algorithm2e. I have now edited my answer to be compilable. It's only requirement is the algorithm2e package