# Which package to use for writing algorithms?

Tags: listings, algorithms, code, pseudocode

I am looking for a package that will allow me to write pseudocode 
of algorithms. The pseudocode may include mathematical symbols, like
`\forall`, `\in` and subscripts. But I would like also to "talk" about
variables contained in the pseudocode in my text, so be able to say "In figure ...
variable `foobar` corresponds .." and make the word `foobar` have the same appearance
as in the pseudocode example.

I found that with the `listings` package
I can add mathematical symbols by using: `\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]`. The problem
with this package is that I don't know how to make just one word have the
same appearance as the words appearing inside `\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}`.

Any ideas how to do this? 
Or perhaps of another package that will help solve the above
mentioned problem?

Comment: You may want to look at the packages `algorithm2e` and `algorithmic`

Comment: Not really pseudo-code, but I like the _old fashioned_ Nassi–Shneiderman diagrams. See [struktex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/struktex)

Comment: @egreg Thank you for answering. By passing the documentations of the two packages you suggest I see how I can add math symbols to my code. But I cannot see how to solve the second problem: "make just one word have the same appearance as the words appearing". Any ideas for this?

Comment: @equality Do you mean a new keyword?

Comment: @egreg Yes, somehow. For example, I would like to be able to write: "As seen in algorithm 2, `keyword` is used for this purpose" and `keyword` will have the same style/font as in the algorithm.

Comment: Does this question help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1375/8569

Comment: @matth No, unfortunately not. I cannot see how I can do the second thing I asked :(

Comment: The inline equivalent of `\begin{lstlisting}\end{lstlisting}` is `\lstinline{}`

Comment: @knittl thanks that was what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment is part of the “*listings*” package.

Additionally to providing an environment for listings (`\begin{lstlisting}`) and a command to import code from files (`\lstinputlisting`), it also provides a command to highlight code inline: `\lstinline`.

Be aware, that `\lstinline` has some limitations though (and does not obay all options from `lstset`)

Answer (score 18):

Using any one of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) or [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) would allow you to typeset pseudocode with your own definitions for variables and keywords. Here is a small example using `algpseudocode` (provided by `algorithmicx`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}% variable
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$ and \var{foobar}\label{foobar}
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
In Algorithm~\ref{euclid}, variable \var{foobar} (in line~\ref{foobar}), corresponds to\ldots
\end{document}
```

Since the contents of the `algorithmic` environment is treated as-is, formatting inside of it is left up to the user to a great extend. Consequently, "variable formatting" can easily be done using a macro that is typeset equivalently inside/outside `algorithmic`. The above example defines `\var{<variable>}` that sets its contents in typewriter font.

Comment: thanks for your answer [+1]:). As I was already using the listings package, I accepted the answer below