# How to choose an algorithm environment?

Tags: algorithms

I know there are multiple packages for typesettings algorithms (`algorithmic`, `algorithmicx`, `algorithm2e`), and some other which are not exactly designed for this exact purpose but can be used as well (`listings`). What I don't know is which to choose.

- What are the pros and cons of the different packages for typesetting algorithms? (I'm asking for an objective survey here.)
- Are there any clear differences among them?
- Which one is more "common" in academic papers?

Comment: `algorithm2e` is for pseudo-code algorithms; `listings` is for verbatim listings.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64170/which-package-to-use-for-writing-algorithms?lq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-a-good-package-for-displaying-algorithms