# Package to load in Lyx to use \quad?

Tags: spacing, lyx

I'm using Lyx software to typeset an algorithm. I'm trying to use the `\quad` command to indent in a loop I'm writing, yet the `\quad` command is not being recognized when I compile the page. I'm assuming I need to load a particular package to use the `\quad` command. Does anyone know what package I should load? Or if it's not a package loading problem, what do I need to do so that I can use `\quad`.

Comment: Please refer to this. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Make sure to insert it as actual TeX code; plain old text won't be recognized. I believe the shortcut is Ctrl+R.

Comment: Beware of using `\quad` for indenting, because `\hspace` is removed at the beginning of a line (except the first in a paragraph).

Comment: @SeanAllred Ctrl + L, or Insert --> TeX Code.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any additional packages to use `\quad`. If by 'not recognized' you mean that `\quad` doesn't have an effect, it may be because you've added it after a line break (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), where it won't work, as egreg mentioned in a comment.  Instead, use `\hspace*{1em}` in an ERT, or do Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal space, using a custom length and with *Protect* checked:

[image]

However, I don't think you'd really want to use `\quad`, or similar manual spacing, to write algorithms, it would be better to use one of the several existing LaTeX packages for that purpose.

See Werner's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64354/586 for an example. To use this in LyX, go first to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

In your document, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or Insert --> TeX code, and write the entire `algorithm` environment in this, e.g.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b} 
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$ 
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0} 
\State $a\gets b$ 
\State $b\gets r$ 
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$ 
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile} 
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b} 
\EndProcedure 
\end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

The ERT requirement is a drawback, but if you can get https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115729/586 to work then that can be avoided.

Also, if you are content with letting your algorithms be floats (similar to figures and tables), you can modify the above example a little. First, remove `\usepackage{algorithm}` from the preamble. Add an algorithm float with Insert --> Float --> Algorithm. This adds the caption box automatically, and you can add the label as normal. Insert an ERT after the caption, and write the `algorithmic` environment in this, i.e. just

```
\begin{algorithmic} 
...
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]