# Package algorithm to use

Tags: packages, algorithms

Please, what package can i use in latex to have the model of algorithm in the figure ?
[image: figure algorithm]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1375/5701

Comment: Have you tried `algorithm2e`?

Comment: algorithm2e let me to write a pseudo algorithm ? because my algorithm is just  a set of sentences, it is not a true algorithm..

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have connecting loop lines (like `algorithm2e`) in `algorithmic`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52473/5764)

Comment: See Werner's excellent answer at [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/25429#25429).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in a comment, the [`algorithm2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) package gives you the desired layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\Begin{
$V \longleftarrow U$\;
$S \longleftarrow \emptyset$\;
\For{$x\in X$}{
$NbSuccInS(x) \longleftarrow 0$\;
$NbPredInMin(x) \longleftarrow 0$\;
$NbPredNotInMin(x) \longleftarrow |ImPred(x)|$\;
  }
}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\label{alg:test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i have used your code but i don't have the line that connects begin to end. have you an idea please

Comment: with \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} i have resolved the problem

Comment: Please i ask if it's possible to have this same format with package algorithmic, because i should use it

Comment: @researcher You can do it with `algorithmicx` (notice the "x" at the end) which is much better, can do everything `algorithmic` does and they are compatible. See [this answer by Werner] to learn how to achieve the desired layout using `algorithmicx`.

Comment: The function names don't look very pretty. `$\textit{NbSuccInS}(x) \longleftarrow 0$` looks nice and informal.