# How to break a pseudocode box between two pages

Tags: page-breaking, pseudocode

I am using the method [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-a-good-package-for-displaying-algorithms/) to generate my pseudocode, however my code is long and after running the tex file, instead of breaking the code box into two parts, it moves the whole code to the next page. I want to know how can I break it?
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,bezier]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm,fontspec}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\textwidth = 15 cm \textheight = 20 cm \oddsidemargin =0.7 cm
\evensidemargin = 0 cm \topmargin = -0.2 cm
\parskip = 2 mm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{
    {\sf\footnotesize\addfontfeatures{Colour=888888,Numbers=Monospaced}#1}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondition:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondition:}}



    \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
      \caption{Counting mismatches between two packed DNA strings
        \label{alg:packed-dna-hamming}}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed DNA strings of equal length $n$}
        \Statex
        \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
          \Let{$z$}{$x \oplus y$} \Comment{$\oplus$: bitwise exclusive-or}
          \Let{$\delta$}{$0$}
          \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
            \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
              \Let{$\delta$}{$\delta + 1$}
            \EndIf
          \EndFor
          \State \Return{$\delta$}
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

P.S.I removed my text before it, which results in the shift.

Comment: The `algorithm` environment is like `figure` or `table`, so it can't be split across pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Don't use the `algorithm` environment (it's a floating environment so it doesn't admit page breaks).
2. Use `\algstore`, and  `\algrestore` as described in Section **2.6 Breaking up long algorithms** of the documentation for package `algorithmicx`.

A complete example showing both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{18\baselineskip}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed strings of equal length $n$}
  \Statex
  \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
    \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
      \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \State \Return{$\delta$}
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Part 1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
\ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
\State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\EndFor
\State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
\Repeat
\For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
\State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
\For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
\If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
\State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
\State \Comment For some reason we need to break here!
\algstore{bkbreak}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
And we need to put some additional text between\dots
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Part 2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algrestore{bkbreak}
\State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State $l’(i) \leftarrow min$
\EndFor
\State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l’$
\State $l \leftarrow l’$
\Until{$\neg changed$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]