# Referring to a correctly-styled pseudocode procedure name from the main text

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode

I'm using the [recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1376/1401) `algpseudocode` package, and have defined a procedure inside an `algorithmic` environment that I would like to refer to from the main text.  Inside this environment,

```
\Procedure{MyProc}{$x$}
```

and

```
\Call{MyProc}{$y$}
```

both display `MyProc` in what appears to be a nice small-caps style.  I would like this same styling to be applied when I refer to the procedure name from the main text, but I couldn't find a way to do this in [the manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf), and trying to start an "in-line" environment didn't work:

```
Calling the procedure\begin{algorithmic}\Call{MyProc}{$y$}\end{algorithmic} results in
```

It results in the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.418 ...thmic}\Call{MyProc}{$y$}\end{algorithmic}
                                                  , results in
?
```

Any ideas?  Please don't tell me I have to grovel through the `algpseudocode` source code, dig up whatever style it's applying, and hardcode that each time I want to refer to a procedure name...

Thanks!

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Indeed it is, and `\textproc` works, thanks!  Would be nice if `\textproc` was mentioned somewhere in the package's manual, but I'll settle for this.  Also I've edited the title of that question to make it easier to find.

Comment: Since my question is a duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: I doubt it occurred to me to look at the manual when I answered the other question, I would guess I just looked at the source:-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker no need really it'll get closed as dup and do no harm:-)